# Scrape 'dictionary' type object from top of HTML file (bunch of text, not in a class)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Consider this source code: 
view-source:http://www.steepandcheap.com/gear-cache/shop-smartwool-on-sale/SWL00II-GRA

There is a dictionary/JSON type text at the top that starts with "window.BC.product = "

Say I have a soup object of this page. How would I pull out that text on top and turn it into a python dictionary so I can pull out specific data from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate the `script` by checking it's text to contain "window.BC.product".

After you extract the script contents, use regular expressions to extract the desired javascript object, then, load it via `json.loads()` to get the Python dictionary:

```
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

pattern = re.compile(r"window\.BC\.product = (.*);", re.MULTILINE)

response = requests.get("http://www.steepandcheap.com/gear-cache/shop-smartwool-on-sale/SWL00II-GRA")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)   

script = soup.find("script", text=lambda x: x and "window.BC.product" in x).text
data = json.loads(re.search(pattern, script).group(1))
print data
```

Prints:

```
{u'features': [{u'name': u'Material', u'description': u'[shell] 86% polyester, ... u'Zippered back pocket\r', u'Reflective details']}
```